# How to edit background color a TD inside a div and an ID

Tags: html, css

Hi i have the following code and i am trying to Color the background of the TDs inside this little Tab i created.

```HTML
<body>
  <nav class="nav_tabs">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <input type="radio" name="tabs" class="rd_tabs" id="tab2">
        <label for="tab1">Shutdown</label>
        <div class="content">
```

I tried doing like this on the style sheet:

```CSS
.nav_tabs #tab2 .content td
  {
  background: lightcyan;
  }
```

I dont really understand what i am doing wrong but it is not working, i tried different things but nothing.

I cant post the content inside the article but it is mostly tables:

```
<style>
    *
    {
        margin:0;
        padding: 0;
    }

    body    
    {
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    }
    .nav_tabs
    {
        width: 600px;
        height: 400px;
        margin 100px auto;
        background-color: #fff;
        position: relative;

    }

    .nav_tabs ul
    {
        list-style: none;
    }
    .nav_tabs ul li
    {
        float: left;
    }
    .nav_tabs label
    {
        width: 100px;
        padding: 25px;
        background-color: #363b48;
        display:block;
        color: #fff;
        cursor: pointer;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .rd_tabs:checked ~ label
    {
        background-color: #e54e43;
    }

    .rd_tabs
    {
        display: none;
    }
    .content
    {
        border-top: 5px solid #e54e43;
        background-color: #fff;
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        height: 320px;
        width: 600px;
        left: 0;
    }
    .content article
    {
        padding 10px;
    }
    .rd_tabs:checked ~ .content
    {
        display: block;
    }
    .nav_tabs .content td
    {
        background: lightcyan;
    }

</style>    






<body>
    <nav class="nav_tabs">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <input type="radio" name="tabs" class="rd_tabs" id="tab1" 
                checked>
                <label for="tab1">tab1</label>
                <div class="content">
                        <article>                    
                    </article>
    </li>
    <li>
                <input type="radio" name="tabs" class="rd_tabs" id="tab2">
                <label for="tab2">SHUTDOWN (MINIMUM CONFIGURATION)</label>
                <div class="content">
                    <article>                    
                    </article>
    </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <input type="radio" name="tabs" class="rd_tabs" id="tab3">
                <label for="tab3">Tab3</label>
                <div class="content">
                    <article>
                    
                    </article>
                </div>
            </li>         
        </ul>

    </nav>

</body>
```

Comment: I think we're missing some HTML .. namely `#tab2` which probably contains  `.content` and `td` which I am assuming should be inside a table somewhere ..

Comment: Why are you putting a table cell inside of an unordered list?

Comment: <input type="radio" name="tabs" class="rd_tabs" id="tab2">
                <label for="tab2">SHUTDOWN (MINIMUM CONFIGURATION)</label>
                <div class="content">

Comment: @user19103974 i dont really understand the question sorry, still learning.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

try remove `#tab2` in your css

```
.nav_tabs .content td
{
    background: lightcyan;
}
```

i dont see in your html code something like that `id='tab2'` between your`.nav_tabs` and `.content` .
so probably that's why it doesnt work now

update 
if you need change the color of tab2 for example 
so you have to add `id='tab2'` to the `<li>` element 
but it shouldn't be duplicate the id in inputs

Comment: I do have a Tab 2, i just messed up the example sorry, if i take the tab2 out since every tab uses the content div all of them turns cyan. But i need the color of every tab to be different. 
Tab2: <input type="radio" name="tabs" class="rd_tabs" id="tab2">
                <label for="tab2">SHUTDOWN (MINIMUM CONFIGURATION)</label>
                <div class="content">

Comment: @DixtiPeix please edit your original question and place ALL pertinent HTML and CSS

Comment: @Zak just did that thank you.

Comment: @DixtiPeix can you add id to `<li>` tag ? like `<li id='li-tab2>` ? It would be the easiest way to fix everything

Comment: I did and it worked, i just dont understand why it works with the <li> id but not with the input id.

Comment: @DixtiPeix because tag `li` is parent of `.content`, but tag `input` is sibling of `.content` . You can try to use something like this css selector for sibling `.nav_tabs #tab2 ~ .content td`, but I am not sure about that